# why python not crash in this case?

Tags: python

For the example in this page:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/CrashingPython#Exhausting_Resources
Why the case can't be reproduced in my python 2.7 
Why it can make python crash?

```
$ python
Python 2.4.2 (#2, Sep 30 2005, 21:19:01) 
[GCC 4.0.2 20050808 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.0.1-4ubuntu8)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f = lambda: None
>>> for i in xrange(1000000):
...     f = f.__call__
... 
>>> del f
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Bugs are being fixed all the time, including this one. Why should there be a specific explanation as to why this can't be reproduced in Python 2.7?

Comment: I can't even reproduce this with Python 2.4.6, so that gives you a nice narrow range to go search the [change history](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.4/Misc/NEWS).

Comment: And there we have it: http://bugs.python.org/issue532646, fixed in Python 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a bug, see [issue #532646](http://bugs.python.org/issue532646).

All software has bugs, and the Python project is no exception. It can't be reproduced in 2.7 because the bug was found and fixed.

Specifically, the page you found documents various such crashing bugs, and it states so *at the top*:

> While a lot of effort has gone into making it difficult or impossible to crash the Python interpreter in normal usage, there are lots fairly easy ways to crash the interpreter. The BDFL pronounced recently on the python-dev mailing list:
>
> > I'm not saying it's uncrashable. I'm saying that if you crash it, it's a bug unless proven harebrained.

Any known, still outstanding bugs are added to the [crashers test suite](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/test/crashers). If you follow back the history on those tests, you'll be able to find more crashers and the versions of Python they apply to. Most require obscure setups like the one in your question.